# Django loop over modelchoicefield queryset

Tags: python, django

### My Problem:

I need to loop over the queryset of a `ModelChoiceField` in my template so that I can create a radio button list that includes the area field of the model along with the description field. So my model looks like this...

models.py

```
class AnExample(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    area = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.area
```

...and I'd like to create radio button inputs in my template, so that the form would look like this:

`<input type="radio">{{ model_instance.area }}: {{ model_instance.description }}`

### What I've tried:

```
{% for choice in form_from_view.an_example.field.choices %}
    {{ choice }}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me a list of tuples with the primary key and area, but **I do not have access to the description field** if I do this.

```
{% for item in form_from_view.an_example.field.queryset %}
    {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

This gives me the actual model instance, and I do have access to `{{ item.description }}` but unfortunately this doesn't loop over the entire queryset; **it only gives me the first record, not each record in the queryset** like I'd expect.

### Other

views.py

`form_from_view = MyForm(instance=my_form_instance)`

forms.py

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    an_example = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        queryset=AnExample.objects.all(),
        required=True)
```

`AnExample.objects.all()` should return 3 records. I can verify that in the admin.

Comment: What is `form_from_view` here?

Comment: @DanielRoseman The form variable that I define in my `views.py` before I send it to the template with `locals()` in `render_to_response`

Comment: Yes but what is it? *Show the code*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to loop over field choices in the template. Instead, you should customise the form field itself to give you the output you want.

In the case of a ModelChoiceField, as the documentation explains, the way to customise the output is to subclass the field and define `label_from_instance`:

```
class AnExampleModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return '{}: {}'.format(obj.area, obj.description)

class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    an_example = forms.AnExampleModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect,
        queryset=AnExample.objects.all(),
        required=True)
```

Now you can just do `{{ form_from_view.an_example }}` in your template to output the whole thing.